# How can I add a sound wave on top of an existing one, without harming the original's loudness?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I'm working on a program that has to do with adding sound waves on top of sound waves. Currently what I'm doing is simply an average of the two waves. So if I have wave `A`, and I want to write wave `B` 'on top' of it, every sample in the new `A` is equal to the average of two matching samples in the original waves.

This works decently, however sometimes it leads to a significant decrease of loudness in wave `A`. Is there a better way to combine sound waves?

For example, if I have a sound wave of a guitar playing, I want to be able to add on top of it a sound wave of a saxophone playing, without decreasing the volume of the guitar. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I think this is off topic here, but if so we could migrate it to [dsp.SE].

Comment: Why not just sum them, rather than average them?

Comment: Do all the math in floating point, and normalize the data when it comes time to write ints to the output file.

Comment: Bear in mind that sounds can mask one another. This is an effect of human perception of sound. However, people do not notice this as a rule, so I doubt it's an issue for you. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking

Answer (score 2):

You just add them.  There is no reason to take an average.

Comment: except, of course, to prevent clipping/overflow or any other reason you don't want the total energy to increase as much as it would by just adding.  (but i up-arrowed the answer.)

Comment: and it probably should be migrated to dsp.se.

Comment: Reducing the amplitude to prevent clipping would change the loudness.

Comment: not (necessarily) the total loudness (that of `A` and `B` together).  but yes, it would reduce the loudness of wave `A`.  the point is that there *are* reasons (not *"no reason"*) to average or to use AGC or level compression.